# Why does Visual Studio change app.config if a NuGet package is added?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

After adding a deliberate NuGet package to a .NET Framework project (version 4.8 in my case) typically two types of files change: packages.config and csproj file.
But sometimes also the app.config becomes changed and if there is no app.config file yet then Visual Studio adds one. See example here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.4" newVersion="7.0.0.4" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Why is that? Why are package.json and csproj not enough? And do I have to deploy app.config to the production machine? Normally I would only deploy an app.config file if my application had the need for configuration options. If I don't want to 'pollute' the target system can I omit the generated app.config files or would I get runtime errors at some point?

Comment: A different NuGet package has a depencency lower than the version you are currently adding, those lines say "hey, listen guys, all of you who have a dependeny on Binder use version 7.0.0.4 instead of the version you where build against."

Comment: Hi FarwoodHill, any update of this issue, does my answer answer your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because there are dependencies which uses the same dll but different versions. That line in the app.config tells the application to just go ahead and grab the highest version of the dll. It's therefore required.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Answer (score 0):

As this document mentioned:

[Rely on automatic binding redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions#rely-on-automatic-binding-redirection)

`<bindingRedirect>` is used to specify version redirection of dependent assemblies. When the program needs to load an assembly at runtime, this element can tell the runtime which version of the assembly should be loaded. In your example, the value of the oldVersion attribute is 0.0.0.0-7.0.0.4, which means that all assemblies of 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder' with versions between 0.0.0.0 and 7.0.0.4 (inclusive) will be redirected to the new version 7.0.0.4.

I don't know what your program is like, but if you are not very sure that your program does not need it, I suggest you deploy app.config to prevent some strange problems occur.

> Why are package.json and csproj not enough?

I think you make a typo? package.json seems a concept in nodejs, do you mean package.config?

package.config and csproj directly manage nuget package version, but app.config doesn't. app.config is mainly used to configure application settings such as connection strings, assembly binding redirection, etc.